# How to reformat column in place using strsplit()

Tags: r

In my r dataframe, I have a column that looks like this:

```
df$Year

"Cumulative.12.2013.Actual"
"Cumulative.12.2014.Actual"
"Cumulative.12.2015.Actual"
"Cumulative.12.2016.Actual"
"Cumulative.12.2017.Actual"
"Cumulative.12.2018.Actual"
"Cumulative.12.2019.Actual"
"Cumulative.5.2020.Actual"
```

I'm trying to re-format the column such that I only include the dates. It should look like:

```
df$Year

"12/2013"
"12/2014"
"12/2015"
"12/2016"
"12/2017"
"12/2018"
"12/2019"
"5/2020"
```

How can I achieve this? I tried doing it all in one line, but all it returns in `df$Year` is `"12/2013"` for all the rows :

```
df$Year< - paste(strsplit(df$Year, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2], strsplit(x, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][3], sep="/")
```

Comment: use gsub("\\D", "", x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option.

```
df$Year %<>% 
  as.character %>% 
  strsplit(.,"([a-zA-Z]\\.)|(\\.[a-zA-Z])") %>% 
  sapply( .,function(i) i[2] %>% 
  gsub(".","/",.,fixed=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `strsplit` for this. It would be better to use something like `gsub`.

```
gsub("^[^0-9]+(\\d+).(\\d+)[^0-9]+$", "\\1/\\2", x)
## [1] "12/2013" "12/2014" "12/2015" "12/2016" "12/2017" "12/2018" "12/2019" "5/2020"
```

There are many other alternatives. For example this is a hack I picked up from @akrun that would be useful here (and probably the fastest, given the nature of the data):

```
sub(".", "/", trimws(x, whitespace = "[^0-9]"), fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "12/2013" "12/2014" "12/2015" "12/2016" "12/2017" "12/2018" "12/2019" "5/2020"
```

Or you could do this:

```
sub(".", "/", gsub("Cumulative.|.Actual", "", x), fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "12/2013" "12/2014" "12/2015" "12/2016" "12/2017" "12/2018" "12/2019" "5/2020"
```

If you didn't need the forward slash for the date, you could even do something like this instead:

```
gsub("Cumulative.|.Actual", "", x)
## [1] "12.2013" "12.2014" "12.2015" "12.2016" "12.2017" "12.2018" "12.2019" "5.2020"
```

Sample data:

```
x <- c("Cumulative.12.2013.Actual", "Cumulative.12.2014.Actual", "Cumulative.12.2015.Actual", 
    "Cumulative.12.2016.Actual", "Cumulative.12.2017.Actual", "Cumulative.12.2018.Actual", 
    "Cumulative.12.2019.Actual", "Cumulative.5.2020.Actual")
```